# Windows Server Shared Folder is Visible to 192.168.1.0 but not 192.168.2.0

Tags: windows, networking, router, shared-folders

I face an issue regarding file sharing between Windows computers over different sub-networks.

The network topology is as shown here:

[image: network topology]

There are two sub-networks which are connected together with PPPT by using two Mikrotik routers (please ignore the figure showing PPPoE).

The purpose is to make the Windows 2008 server (that is part of the 192.168.1.0 sub-network) accessible to all computers for file sharing.

So far, computers A and B are able to access the shared folders of the server.

Unfortunately, the shared folders of the server are not visible to computers C and D.

I would like to mention that computers A and B can ping computers C and D and vice versa even if they belong in different sub-networks.
Also, all computers can ping the Server.

So, even if all computers are visible to each other why can't computers C and D "see" the shared folders of the server?

All computers use Windows 10.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Comment: Please define "see" more precisely. Are you trying to: a) use Windows network device discovery to automatically list computers with shared folders? b) directly connect to remote computers using their hostnames (`\\hostname\share`)? c) directly connect to remote computers using their IP addresses (`\\192.168.1.3\share`)?

Comment: What have you done to be able to ping between the two segments? Why don't you have everything simply exist in the same segment?

Comment: My first attempt was to use Windows Network Device Discovery which did not show any computers on the network. What actually worked was grawity's suggestion to directly connect to the remote computers using their IP addresses. Additionally, to answer to harrymc the network is installed in such way to connect two facilities located in different places. I am not aware of any details because the network was set up by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the following given by user grawity:

> Please define "see" more precisely. Are you trying to: a) use Windows
>   network device discovery to automatically list computers with shared
>   folders? b) directly connect to remote computers using their hostnames
>   (\hostname\share)? c) directly connect to remote computers using
>   their IP addresses (\192.168.1.3\share)?

Answer (score 0):

Dont have rep to comment..

Try enabling insecure guest logons in your GP restart and try that.

If you torch 192.168.1.3 on your mikrotik can you see the request reaching that machine?

Comment: I was able to access the torch tool in our mikrotik router but I could not do much due to lack of knowledge background. In the end, the solution was much simpler than I thought (given by user grawity). Nevertheless, thank you for your suggestion!